# Detection of Hazmat labels (diamond shaped squares) using openCV

Tags: opencv, detection

I have to detect hazMat labels which are square shaped but depending upon the camera location they do not appear as perfect squares most of the time.

To have a look of hazmat labels and the background i have (the red color sign is hazMat sign)....please see the following link:

https://wiki.cc.gatech.edu/robocup/images/9/9b/Box3.jpg

***Techniques i have tried so far:***

1. **Generalized hough transform:** It didn't work because the shape keep changing depending upon the webcam location.
2. **Color based segmentation** and then Contour detection: It didn't work because the hazMat labels are of different color and many times the color difference between the background & Hazmat label is not too much.
3. **Detection of contours having 4 point** and eliminating small & very big contours: It also didn't work. The results are good and it is detecting quadrilateral except my Hazmat labels.

Kindly tell me, what other technique (or combination of techniques) i can try??

Comment: one technique alone might achieve poor results only. try combining contour / color detection

Comment: @berak: i have already tried to do color based segmentation firtst and then extract contour. But the results were very poor because as i mentioned that background creates problem in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect the circle you need to execute the Canny algorithm to the Image processing part.
then execute the cvt converstion to the MAT image
At last implement the Houghcircle for circle. or go to the Find contours scenario.

This is what i have just detected. check the image .

[image: The shape dettected]

Comment: They are of diamond/square shaped not circular...and i have also found a solution to my problem by using the opencv's square.c with modification

Comment: Use find contours that will help it has helped me

Comment: check this question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396674/detection-of-different-shapes-dynamically-like-circle-square-and-rectangle

Comment: send me your mail id will send you the complete source code.. of my project if you need it

Comment: check your mail. Njoy

Comment: i checked...but i haven't got anything. Id is so_flow2014@yahoo.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47016/discussion-between-balu-and-user2440724)